# How do I switch Hosting provider with Cloudflare enabled?

Tags: dns, web-hosting, cloudflare

I have Cloudflare enabled for my domain which points to my current hosting IPs but I will be switching to another hosting provider in the coming days. How do I do the transition without having to disable and set up Cloudflare all over again?

Answer (score 0):

You simply change the IP's in the Cloudflare interface whenever the new hosting is ready. If you are using the Cloudflare caching proxy, that should be nearly instantaneous. If you are just using them for DNS, there will be a period of time where some traffic will be sent to the new host, and some to the old host. This depends on the TTL specified on the DNS record.